# Why RelatedObjectDoesNotExist is thrown when trying to add an entery from the django admin?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

In my models, I have the ImageAlbum model and Image model. In the Image model, I have a ForeignKey field to the ImageAlbum. This code is actually recommended from [this](https://medium.com/ibisdev/upload-multiple-images-to-a-model-with-django-fd00d8551a1c) article.

```
class ImageAlbum(models.Model):

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.pk)


class Image(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_upload_path)
    default = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_thumbnail_path, default='default/default_thumbnail.jpg')
    album = models.ForeignKey(ImageAlbum, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I registered the models in the admin and the Image form looks like that:

[image: Django admin form throwing RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at ForeignKey field]

And after I hit save, the following exception occurs:

[image: Django admin throwing RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at ForeignKey field]

Comment: Is that the actual code for your `ImageAlbum` model? Your error doesn't match up to it really. Is some other `model` related to it? Please show the proper code for the model, especially its actual `__str__` method.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat You made a good point. That helped me debug the problem. I managed to find where the problem actually was. In the `Image` model, in the function that I was setting the uploading path, there was a call of a method that didn't existed, thus the RelatedObjectDoesNotExist and the info that the ImageAlbum has no `model`.

Answer (score 1):

Your `ImageAlbum` Model should look like this .

```
class ImageAlbum(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', blank=True) # new

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.pk)
```

Migrate first and then Check again this would work.

Comment: Well... I have the ImageAlbum as a sort of  collection of multiple images. That's why I have on my `Image` model a ForeignKey to ImageAlbum. Even though your solution would solve the errors, it would not fit my desired functionality.

Comment: You should create an another app for images and bind them with many to many Field relation where you want . That is another way to mix multiple images for one entry.

Comment: As here i am using the same approach .. https://github.com/faisalnazik/Django-REST-framework-React.JS-Typescript/tree/master/Backend . Consider Video app as images app and this would do the job for you .

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue, in my case it had to do with the migrations. I re-ran migrations afresh after clearing them out and that solved the issue you are highlighting. Of cause this was on a local dev environment with a SQLite db setup, you may not have such a luxury in production.